# Error al crear bean

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

Estoy aprendiendo lo básico de Spring y tengo el siguiente error al iniciar mi aplicacion.

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2017-12-17
>   18:37:36.331 ERROR 6748 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'exampleComponent': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'courseJpaRepository'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'courseJpaRepository': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class
>   com.udemy.entity.Course   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]     at
>   com.udemy.backendninja.BackendninjaApplication.main(BackendninjaApplication.java:16)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'courseJpaRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Not a managed type: class com.udemy.entity.Course     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     ... 19 common
>   frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class com.udemy.entity.Course   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:68)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:173)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:106)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:88)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:200)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     ... 29 common
>   frames omitted

**Mi Application**

```
package com.udemy.backendninja;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.udemy")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.udemy.repository")
@EntityScan("com.udemy.repository")
public class BackendninjaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendninjaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Mi clase CourseJpaRepository**

```
package com.udemy.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.udemy.entity.Course;

@Repository("courseJpaRepository")
public interface CourseJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Serializable> {


}
```

**Mi clase ExampleComponent**

```
package com.udemy.component;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.udemy.repository.CourseJpaRepository;

@Component("exampleComponent")
public class ExampleComponent {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ExampleComponent.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("courseJpaRepository")
    private CourseJpaRepository courseJpaRepository;

    public void sayHello()
    {
        LOG.info("HELLO FROM EXAMPLEcomponent");
    }

}
```

Las anotaciones @EnableJpaRepositories y @EntityScan tuve que añadirlas ya que me daba otro error y en el sitio encontre que la solucion era añadir dichas anotacones.

**Estructura de mi proyecto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la traza que has indicado, te lo dice, solo hace falta ver donde está el error:

```html
Not a managed type: class com.udemy.entity.Course
```

Para que Course se pueda utilizar en CourseJpaRepository, tendrías que indicar que se escanee el paquete en el que se encuentra, que es "com.udemy.entity". Veo que en la clase BackendninjaApplication escaneas las entidades en el paquete "com.udemy.repository".

Partiendo de la información que has facilitado, ese es el error que se ve cláramente. Para que lo veas más fácilmente te voy a poner el código que tienes que poner en la clase BackendninjaApplication:

```js
package com.udemy.backendninja;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.udemy")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.udemy.repository")
// El cambio está en la siguiente anotación, le tienes que indicar donde estan las entidades, de lo contrario no pueden ser usadas como tal.
@EntityScan("com.udemy.entity")
public class BackendninjaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendninjaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Espero que te haya aclarado el porqué no puede iniciar tu aplicación.

Comment: Mario, me has solucionado un problema que me dio dolores de cabeza por un dia. Muchas gracias.!

Comment: Gracias por tu solución Mario, no sabia que se tenia que indicar la ruta del repository y los entity en la clase principal, pense que con el @Repository ya lo hacia.